# How to optimize CSS animatons (scale, rotate, blur)

Tags: html, css, css-animations

The following HTML example consists of two pictures; one background, the other is an object. Both are animated using scale and rotate. On full HD monitors it tends to be choppy. When you look at the performance in Firefox it gets about 20 fps.

First I used jQuery; to improve performance I chose CSS, but it's still not perfect. In order to reproduce the problem go to full screen. How can I make it better?

```css
.html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #121212;
}

.maincontainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url(http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/beautiful-pictures-of-nature/beautiful-pictures-of-nature-2.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -99;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bg2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -99;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.rain {
  background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/OvFQrZk8b5N0Q/source.gif);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}

.animate-bg {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateBg;
  animation-name: animateBg;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 35000;
  animation-duration: 35000ms;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.3, 0, .7, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.3, 0, .7, 1);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


/* Zoom in Keyframes */

@-webkit-keyframes animateBg {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3) rotate(4deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animateBg {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3) rotate(4deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
}


/*End of Zoom in Keyframes */

.eagle {
  background-image: url(https://pngriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Download-Flying-Eagle-PNG-Image.png);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.animate-eagle {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 35000;
  animation-duration: 35000ms;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.3, 0, .7, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.3, 0, .7, 1);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: animateeagle;
  animation-name: animateeagle;
}


/* Zoom in Keyframes */

@-webkit-keyframes animateeagle {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8) rotate(0deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1.05) rotate(-2deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animateeagle {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1.05) rotate(-2deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
}


/*End of Zoom in Keyframes */

.blur {
  animation: blur 5000ms;
}

@keyframes blur {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

.unblur {
  animation: unblur 1000ms;
}

@keyframes unblur {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes unblur {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontainer">

  <div id="bg2" class="bg2">
    <div id="bg" class="bg animate animate-bg">
      <div class="rain"></div>
      <div class="drops"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="eagle">
    <div class="eagle animate-eagle">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The suggested duplicate question isn't related because I don't see how this can be solved with canvas.

Comment: If not processed, `//` are not valid CSS comments...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS animation performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996102/css-animation-performance)

Comment: @Ikillnukes I dont see how my problem can be solved with canvas or js related stuff mentioned in that questions answer.

Comment: You can force hardware acceleration with CSS by using `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)`. For me it didn't affect much though.

Comment: Can you explain me what's the problem? it works as it should on my screen

Comment: @MarcoSalerno If you check the performance under developer tool you will see that framerate is low. In full screen ofc. This also depends on your pc configuration.
Looking for a way to optimize the animations.

Comment: I tried using the performance tab but i can't see the fps number, where is it? If you tell me i try to solve ^^

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the will-change attribute, potentially this may help you get it a bit smoother, you can read about it [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/)

it doesn't have the greatest browser support thats the only thing.

I suspect your 1px blur on the rain is probably quite intensive, you are bluring something that is constantly changing. I can't quite see where you are using the .blur class and related animation, but that will be quite expensive for performance.

`transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` as Robert Moore suggests helps webkit particularly to use hardware acceleration, you can read about it [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css) however in this instance as you are using filters these are already taking advantage of hardware acceleration

Answer (score 5):

That's because you're blurring an animated GIF in real-time.

Remove `-webkit-filter: blur(1px);` and the lag is gone.

I tried recreating the [rain effect with a canvas element](https://codepen.io/ruigewaard/pen/JHDdF?limit=all&page=5&q=rain) but got the same result so the GIF is not the problem here.

The issue is that Firefox seems to be struggling with the blur filter on animated elements.

(Not really an answer, but too long for a comment)